# how to import a language (for messages comments e.g. persians) in C language

Tags: c

1  -  i'm work with some devices for transaction data - Card and Card Readers
one of them executes in C language, and I should put some messages and comments into options with native language (Persian language) but I don't know How can I Do it!
Should I import a specific header file ?
Thank you

---

2   -   unfortunately C languages in these devices are limited when modify and save into unicode, doesn't work and show unknown characters ! also I can't use images for option.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use unicode characters. [This](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html) should help you out .